# Expand the div to "read more"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, css

I come across a problem in my site to which I am finding a solution. Posts are fetched from the MySQL database. If it contains a few lines,it is displayed completely.But,if it contains too many lines (thus taking more space on the browser screen),then I want it to be displayed as a single line followed by dots (for example, your too long posts....) with a "see more" option by clicking which the entire post is displayed (as seen in facebook,twitter etc). Is it a client-side solution by javascript or jquery or can be handled server-side by PHP. Your advice is much appreciated!

The entire post is fetched from MySQL and I straightway echo it:

```
<?php
 //code
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
   echo $row['posts'];
 }
?>
```

At this moment I simply fetch the entire post from database and echo it.I want here a javascript solution to do the rest.

Comment: This could be handled in any way, but hardly w/o JS at all. What have you tried already?

Comment: Please provide the code you've already tried.

Comment: The advantage of handling it with a hybrid solution (server-side + client-side) is that long posts will not be downloaded to the browser until the user clicks 'read more'.

Comment: The question is about which way it has to be handled, not how it is handled. I suppose that it depends. If the DOM gets cluttered with info that will rarely be seen (such as a list of items), then I would call the text content from the server through Ajax and display it with jQuery / js.

Comment: thanks @KimGysen I have edited my answer above. I have no idea about what to do right now....

Comment: The question is also: will you return the entire block of text with PHP and hide superfluous text from the downloaded text chunk(s) with Javascript, or will you cut down some text with PHP and call it later with Ajax? I'd say, minimize downloading the amount of text that the user will likely never see. If you have a list of read mores, the chance of needing all entire texts is small. If you have a single page with read more and the extra text has acceptable size, then you can download it at once. -> Answers below already :-)

Comment: you are right @KimGysen. Your points are too good to be noted. Suppose, I have a field with data type varchar,then how do I fetch only a segment of the field in a record instead of fetching the entire field data as mentioned in your comment?

Comment: You can return part of the string by using the `substr()` function: http://be2.php.net/substr. Or you can do it in the SQL query directly: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx Or MySQL: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML & PHP** :

```
<?php
$text = '. . .';
$limit = 100;
?>
<div class="text">
    <?php
    if (strlen($text) < $limit) {
        echo $text;
    } else {
        echo substr($text, 0 , $limit);
        echo "<br/><a href='#' onclick='showMore()'>read more</a>";
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

**jQuery** :

```
<script>
    function showMore() {
        var text = '<?php echo $text; ?>'
        $(".text").html(text);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It pushes me to the right direction as I thought something like this before.... thanks Fallah

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with jquery :-

```
<div class="columns">
    your text goes here. Try long text here....
</div>

 a.morelink {
        text-decoration: none;
        outline: none;
    }

    .morecontent span {
        display: none;
    }

    .comment {
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        margin: 10px;
    }

<script>
var showChar = 120;
        var ellipsestext = "...";
        var moretext = "more";
        var lesstext = "less";

        $(".columns").each(function () {
            var content = $(this).html();

            if (content.length > showChar) {
                var first = content.substr(0, showChar);
                var second = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);

                var html = first + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + second + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

                $(this).html(html);
            }
        });

        $(".morelink").click(function(){
            if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                $(this).removeClass("less");
                $(this).html(moretext);
            } else {
                $(this).addClass("less");
                $(this).html(lesstext);
            }
            $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
            $(this).prev().toggle();
            return false;
        }); 
</script>
```

Comment: What is 'comment' class for?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
<?php
    $str = 'simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's';
    $limit = 40;
    if(strlen($str)>$limit){
        $stringCut = substr($str, 0, $limit);
        $serRpos = strrpos($stringCut, ' ');
        $first_part = substr(substr($str, 0, $limit), 0,$serRpos);
        $last_part = substr($str,$serRpos);
        echo $first_part;
        echo '<span style="cursor: pointer" onclick="showText(this)"> ...<span class="hide-text" style="display: none;">'.$last_part.'</span></span>';
    }
    else{
        echo $str;
    }
?>
```

and the script(i used jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showText(e){
$(e).html($(e).find('.hide-text').html());
}
</script>
```